# How to fix the error, that is caused by updating elementor?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor

When I update Elementor on my WP, there's a conflict with my theme (BigHeartsCore).

I staged the page and deactivated every plugin. But when I activate the "BigHearts Core" there is a crash to the whole site.

- There are different errors that appear in the Error Log after updating Elementor without problems and than activating the Plugin "BigHeartsCore":

```
12:59:01 \[error\] 305771#305771: \*2023 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function save_scheme() on bool in /home/wp/disk/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/bighearts-core/includes/elementor/init.php:517
```

I staged the page and deactivated every plugin. Than I updated the Elementor. After that I tried to activate every plugin to search the conflict. And it accured, that the "BigHeartsCore"-Plugin is the problem. If it's not active, there are no problems. But if I activate it, the whole side crushes and I have to play the backup.q

Comment: The issue you have is that the developer of BigHeartsCore hasn't updated their theme framework to work with the newest version of Elementor. You'll have to roll back Elementor, contact BigHeartsCore developers/support, wait for them to issue an update, consume that, then update Elementor.  This is a common issue when relying entirely on third parties.